# Detect an integer overflow in ASCII-to-integer conversion

Tags: c, integer

I have a `buf` `char*` with ASCII digits where I need to convert to an integer value on 32-bit machine.The `INT_MAX` constant from `limits.h` header give me: `printf("%d\n",INT_MAX)` = `2147483647`. I added plus one, and put exactly this number to my function convert. By it doesn't catch up such large integer value. Would someone explain it?

My first solution:

`if((unsigned int)v >= INT_MAX)` doesn't work to really large numbers.

second solution:

`if(v < 0)` - it works, but:

1) I'm not sure if it safe really

2) I'll provide support for negative numbers in soon, so, it isn't appropriated.

Here's the current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{

  int v = 0;
  char* numbers = "2147483648";
  char* p=numbers;
  while(*p && isdigit(*p)) {
    if((unsigned int)v >= INT_MAX) {
      fprintf(stderr,"too large number");
      exit(1);
    }
    v = v * 10 + (*p - '0');
    p++;
  }
  printf("%d\n",v);
  return 0;
}
```

This output `-2147483648` instead of exit on `if()` test.

There's implementations that use some assembly code to catch such overflows with helps to `jo` instruction. Is this the more appropriate way to go?

Note: I haven't specified platform because it need to portable in any C compiler to 32bit machines.

Comment: If you are not already aware of it, John Regehr organized a contest where the challenge was to implement a function `str2long` while avoiding all undefined behaviors including undefined overflows. You can see how tens of experienced programmers approached the problem you are facing there: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/914

Comment: Here is one entry that was found correct (looking at it, I now realize that many entries were found to have issues. It was actually a difficult contest): https://github.com/regehr/str2long_contest/blob/master/yolanpa.c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is this:

```
if (INT_MAX/10 < v || INT_MAX/10 == v && INT_MAX%10 < *p - '0')
{
    fprintf(stderr,"too large number");
    exit(1);
}
v = v * 10 + (*p - '0');
```

The first condition, `INT_MAX/10 < v`, tests whether `v * 10` will overflow. The second condition, `INT_MAX/10 == v && INT_MAX%10 < *p - '0'`, tests whether the addition of `*p - '0'` will overflow.